# Anyone know of a generic transactional Map | Set | List

Tags: java, collections, transactions

The only real available library i could find was the [Apache Commons Transaction Library](http://commons.apache.org/transaction/).

**Problems w/ Apache Commons Transctions**

- Last release 2008 (3years)
- not generic
- dependency on a logging f/w - do we need a logger for a Map !?!
- i *think* i saw somewhere (prolly the doco) that it was not XA.

**Features id like**

- available collections should be generic
- changes should be batched until a rollback ( forget all changes) or commit.
- dirty reads etc should also be a feature.
- thread independent, different threads should be able to participate in different txs.
- views should also be transaction - e.g. Map.entrySet()
- XA would be nice just so the collection instance can participate in a two phase commit.

Comment: can you tell what exactly transactional you'd like to see. if it can include locking it's relatively trivial to implement, there is a lock-free version of transactional map too. And what's the matter w/ generics, you need to run java1.4 w/ the old memory model?

Comment: @bestsss OP says he wants generics.

Comment: @mP: What do you mean by transactional?  If you're looking for full ACID semantics, you're going to be out of luck, but if you need need e.g. atomicity or units-of-work, then it's going to be easier.

Comment: @biziclop: me stupid :D, either way you can declare any map as Map<K, V> (even if not compiled w/ 1.5+) and it will make no difference impl.-wise. So this is the reason I thought 'no generics'.

Comment: I start to wonder if an in memory database might be a simpler answer. Why do you need this? I'd be interested to know what the scenario is that would need it.

Comment: @ Derek Clarkson: any hashtable type of impl. of a "Map" will be horrendously faster than a in-mem DB (since the in-mem DB will have maps/indexes/trees, etc). basically the look ups are O(1). and in case of a lock-free impl. is well: lock-free.

Comment: bestsss: an in-mem DB can easily provide O(1) access to many things as well. However, your constant `k` might be bigger, as you are implying.

Comment: actually what I don't get now is: "Features id like:: single threaded", what's the point having single threaded transactions.

Comment: @bestsss, transactions are always tied to the thread of execution. i will fix features...

Comment: @skaffman by transaction i mean, changes are committed when the tx, rolled back if the tx fails etc, the ID bits of ACID of course wont be htere as its just a memory map.

Comment: Just out of curiousity: would you need per-entry locking too?

Comment: @biziclop prolly not. locking per entry seems a bit excessive for a map/collection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infinispan is a full XA enabled Cache that also [implements](http://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/4.0/apidocs/org/infinispan/Cache.html) a ConcurrentMap since version 4.

Comment: can Infinispan be used as a non-cache? I mean guarantee to not drop old element.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [JDBM](https://github.com/jankotek/JDBM3) fits your bill? It has transactional disk-backed collection implementations.

Comment: There is newer version named MapDB available now. Check out https://github.com/jankotek/mapdb

Answer (score 3):

I guess the, somewhat frustrating, but obvious, answer is:

If you require database functionality, why not use a database?

If you use an in-memory solution like HyperSonic (HSQL) you have almost no setup to do and you have transactions and many other features built-in

Comment: Becuause all i want/need a Map | Set | List. I dont want to bring in HSQL and have to write adapters for Map | Set | List to and from HSQL. From a theoretical perspective a in memory solution like HSQL will be quite ineffficient as all operations will result in many selects etc.

Answer (score 0):

http://commons.apache.org/transaction/index.html provides wrappers to map for transactional access, including transaction levels such as serializable.

Comment: * not xa, dead ? nearly 3 years since a release